# ngFor with ngBootstrap NgbModal Open - Angular Bootstrap

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor, ng-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap-modal

I am having an issue with calling an NgbModal `open()` within an item rendered within a `*ngFor` loop.

I have a list of items that I want to display. On `click` of said item, I want a modal to open in order to prompt the user for some additional information.

When clicking on the item, I can see the elements get added to the DOM via the DevTools, but the modal does not have the `show` class added to it. The component that should be rendered as the modal's contents is not properly initialized either. If I add the `show` class manually to it, I can see the modal's contents but the component does not work appropriately.

It is important to note that for testing, I added a button subscribed to a click event which passes a fake item to the same function, `setSelected()`. This method of opening the modal works without a problem. The issue only manifests itself when it is within the `*ngFor`.

I have a `console.log` inside of `ConnectionModalComponent`'s (which is being passed as the modal's contents) constructor and another in it's  `ngAfterViewInit`. When activating the modal via a button outside of the `*ngFor`, I see both log statements in the console, but when activating the modal from within the `*ngFor` I only see the constructor's log statement and not the latter.

I am using `@angular/core@12.1.2` & `@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap@10.0.0`.

*testComponent.html.ts* - Component that has the *ngFor

```
        <div>
          <div
            *ngFor="let item of items"
            (click)="setSelected(item)"
          >
            <span class="full-height">
              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-title">
                  {{ item.nickname }}
                </div>
              </div>
            </span>
          </div>
        </div>
```

*testComponent.component.ts* - Function that is called from the HTML template.

```
  public setSelected(item: ItemViewModel): void {
    this.testAlertService.open();
  }
```

*testAlert.service.ts* - Service that is called from the component in order to open the NgbModal.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import { ConnectionModalComponent } from '../../components/shared';

@Injectable()
export class TestAlertService {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open() {
    this.modalService.open(ConnectionModalComponent, { ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title' }).result.then(
      (result) => {
        console.log(`Closed with: ${result}`);
      },
      (reason) => {
        console.log(`Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`);
      }
    );
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue.

Inside of `testComponent.component.ts` where I was pushing to the `items` array, I was using a `detectChanges()` method on the `ChangeDetectorRef` class.

By simply wrapping the array mutation to use `NgZone`'s `run()` solved all my problems.